# bootstrap disabled btn when browser is at 990px, why?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, button

This is a weird issue even though I already have a workaround but does anyone know why this would happen?

I have a button for create post and one for delete all posts

My create post button opens a modal after clicked.

My delete button is placed above of the create post button, code below:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="col-md-6 pull-right">
  <button class="btn btn-danger pull-right" ng-show="showDelBtnAndTableHeaders" ng-click="destroyAll()">
    Delete All Posts
  </button>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg create-new-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#newModal">Create New Post</button>
</div>
```

Somehow when window is at approx **990px or smaller** then the delete button somehow cannot be clicked and hover over doesn't change color too. I checked CSS to see if there's any changes but no changes at all.

If I switch their position or just put the delete anywhere other than above the create button then delete button would work perfectly even at **990px or smaller**.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="col-md-6">
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg create-new-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#newModal">Create New Post</button>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 pull-right">
  <button class="btn btn-danger pull-right" ng-show="showDelBtnAndTableHeaders" ng-click="destroyAll()">
    Delete All Posts
  </button>
</div>
```

Have anyone met this kind of issue or know why this is happening?

Comment: _"the delete button somehow cannot be clicked and hover over doesn't change color too"_ - that most likely means that you have another element on top of it - use the inspect functionality of your browser's developer tools to find out.

Comment: @CBroe I thought of that too but the thing is....I don't see anything on top though... with LJ's edit it happens here too

Comment: Inspecting the right button in the first code snippet clearly shows that the first column goes over the whole width and is on top of the right one. And giving the second `col-md-6` a background color proves it as well.

Comment: @CBroe omg! I get what you mean. I kept on thinking they are at the same row when and I kept on finding something else on top. thx thx another